# DownloadManager inside Fragment Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-download-manager

I am trying to implement DownloadManager inside my fragment class but its giving me error (i am not able to compile the code). Below line where i am getting this:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

Please help me out to solve  this.

Comment: what is the error? what does it say?

Comment: Method is not there i mean i am not able to access by using getActivity()

Comment: where exactly are you implementing this piece of code? In what method?

Comment: getActivity().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

Comment: What kind of Activity class are you using? What kind of Fragment are you using?

Answer (score 7):

change you code line with this one

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

I've edited my code line. it is working :)